# How can I debug generateStaticParams (Next.js) in PhpStorm?

Tags: debugging, next.js, phpstorm, next.js13

I am able to add breakpoints on my Page method but not inside [`generateStaticParams`](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/generating-static-params).

If I add a console.log I can see it is being called at dev and also build time.

I also tried to add `debugger` to the code, but didn't work as well.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: breakpoints in this method are not resolved to me when debugging in PhpStorm and VScode; looks like a sourcemaps issue.

Comment: this proposal looks related: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/20096

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by upgrading from Next.js 13.1.1 to 13.2.1.

My package.json:

```json
//...
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
//...
```

Then just need to click on Debug Dev.
[image: debug dev phpstorm]

[image: debugger stopped at generateStaticParams]

hint: if it does not work, close the browser session, and click on the https://localhost:3000 link within phpstorm run console.